# Error debugging while practicing Recursion

Tags: java, debugging, recursion

I am working on one of recursion practice problems from codingbat

> Q(array11).Given an array of ints, compute recursively the number of times that the value 11 appears in the array. We'll use the convention of considering only the part of the array that begins at the given index. In this way, a recursive call can pass index+1 to move down the array. The initial call will pass in index as 0.

> array11([1, 2, 11], 0) → 1
> array11([11, 11], 0) → 2
> array11([1, 2, 3, 4], 0) → 0

for some reasons, I do not get expected results for certain cases

> array11([1, 2, 11], 0) has to be 1 but I get 0.
> array11([1, 11, 3, 11, 11], 0) has to be 3 but I get 0.

Can you please help me debug my code? Thanks!

```
public int array11(int[] nums, int index) {
    int i = nums.length - 1;
    int check = index;
    int count = 0;
    if (nums.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (nums.length == 1) {
        if (index == 0 && nums[index] == 11) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    if (check == index) {
        if (nums[index] == 11) {
            count += 1;
            return count + 1;
        } else {
            return count;
        }
    } else {
        while (i > check) {
            check++;
            if (nums[check] == 11) {
                count += 1;
                count = count + array11(nums, check);
            } else {
                count = count + array11(nums, check);
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

---

**edit I changed my code tried to make it as efficient as I could. However **

> return 1 + array11(nums, check++);

and

> return array11(nums, check++);

gives me stackoverflow error. In my understanding, whenever it reaches

> if (check > length),

I thought recursion would stop and return the final result. What am I doing wrong and how could I fix this problem?

```
public int array11(int[] nums, int index) {
  int check = index;
  int length = nums.length - 1;
  if (check > length) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    if (nums[check] == 11) {
      return 1 + array11(nums, check++);
    } else {
      return array11(nums, check++);
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Last edit I finally fixed the error**

I used ternary operator for the recursion and it looks clean! Thanks!

```
public int array11(int[] nums, int index) {
  if (index >= nums.length) {
    return 0;
  }
  return (nums[index] == 11) ? 1 + array11(nums, index + 1) : array11(nums, index + 1);
}
```

Comment: int array11(int[] nums, int index) { ... Early checks... return (nums[index]==11 ? 1:0) + array11(nums, index+1); }

Comment: Your code is overly complex. First write a pseudo code then optimize it by reducing the no. of steps and unnecessary steps. The ending condition should be simple and recursive function should be small.

Comment: I fixed my code and tried to optimize it by reducing the number of steps. However, it gives me a stackoverflow error but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Stackoverflow error in recursion means infinite loop. Means your recursive calls are not ending and the next recursion function call is being pushed into the system's memory stack without ever backtracking. Look closely to this code and tell me wheat it means `array11(nums, check++)`. Here you are using post increment operator `check++` means first use check then increment it so in your code first it makes a same call `array11(nums, check);` then after that the value of check is incremented.

Comment: You dont need the variable `check` because you are already passing `index` so use it directly and for next function call pass `index+1`. Dont worry about the parameter value. It seems that you still dont understand recursive calls completely so you think that you need to do ++. See for each function call the parameters are *copied* for new function call unless they are not passed by reference. Read about it more and for your code just pass `+1` instead of `++` and you are good to go.

Comment: And I must say the updated code is much better and cleaner than the old one so keep it up

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! You are the best :)